# Why is my mongoose schema not validating?

Tags: validation, vue.js, mongoose

I am trying to validate my data with mongoose schema. But its not working, and I have no idea why.

This is my Schema

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: { type: String, min: 3, max: 30, required: true },
  password: { type: String, min: 6, required: true }
});

mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

This is where I call the post

```
router.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
    const user = new User({
        username: "Marcel",
        password: "12345"
    })
    user.save().then(function(){
        res.json({
            message: '✅'
        })
    }).catch(function(){
        res.json({
            message: '❌'
        })
    })
})
```

I have given the password a minimum of 6 characters, but with the example user I give 5 characters, so it should not work, but it does. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have used the validators **min** and **max**, which are for the **Number** type.

Try using **minlength** and **maxlength** instead, which are for the **String** type:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: { type: String, minlength: 3, maxlength: 30, required: true },
  password: { type: String, minlength: 6, required: true }
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I feel so stupid, because i thought this was right i was looking at different places where the mistake could be. Thank you

Comment: I have one more doubt, this is not validating type, when we pass number type to string it does not validating. Instead of throwing error it accepts it. (i.e. {
        username: "Marcel",
        password: 1234567    } ). why its not failing? here i have assigned number type to password which actually is a string type.